# Calculate mean based on marker in a second column in R

Tags: r

I have a data set comprised of 1 column of measurements, and 1 column marking events of interest. I would like to calculate the mean of the two measurements following each "Event". So given a sample data set:

```
Data<-c(1,2,3,2,3,4,8,4,2,9,2,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,3)
Event<-c(0,0,0,0,0,"Event",0,0,"Event",0,0,0,"Event",0,0,0,0,"Event",0,0,"Event",0,0,0,0)

DF<-data.frame(Data,Event)


   Data Event
1     1     0
2     2     0
3     3     0
4     2     0
5     3     0
6     4 Event
7     8     0
8     4     0
9     2 Event
10    9     0
11    2     0
12    2     0
```

With an event in row 6, I would want to calulate the mean of rows 7-8 (average of 8 and 4). Next Event at row 9, so average of row 10-11 (mean of 9 and 2) and so on down the rows.

My actual data is a csv with blanks instead of zeros in the Event column, but I couldn't figure out how to set up a DF with blank rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strategy involves finding the index of the rows that have an "Event" and then uses mapply to extract vectors from DF for the two values following the event and take the mean. Finally, i combine the mean with the original event index so you know where it came from.

```
eventsat <- which(DF$Event=="Event")
eventmeans <- mapply(function(a,b) mean(DF$Data[a:b]), eventsat+1, eventsat+2)
cbind(eventsat, means)
```

Admittedly the mapply may be overkill as it would allow for vectors of lengths other than 2, but if it's always two, it's probably just as easy to do

```
eventmeans <- with(DF, (Data[eventsat+1]+Data[eventsat+2])/2)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a quick and dirty way:

```
events <- which(DF$Event=="Event")
sapply(events,function(i)mean(DF[(i+1):(i+2),]$Data))
# [1] 6.0 5.5 2.5 3.0 2.0
```